# Replace character grabbed with imagettftext with a png image

Tags: php, image

My code places glyphs for each of the planets on a horoscope wheel drawn with php.  The glyphs are characters called with 'chr' inside imagettftext, but I think it would be a lot more interesting to use png images to represent the planets.  Can you help?

```
    // here is the 'chr' for each planet
    $pl_glyph[0] = 81;
    $pl_glyph[1] = 87;
    $pl_glyph[2] = 69;

    // display the planet in the wheel
    $angle_to_use = deg2rad($angle_to_use);

    if ($flag == False)
    {
      display_planet_glyph($angle_to_use, $radius - $dist_from_diameter1, $xy);
    }
    else
    {
      display_planet_glyph($angle_to_use, $radius - ($dist_from_diameter2), $xy);
    }
    imagettftext($im, 16, 0, $xy[0] + $center_pt, $xy[1] + $center_pt, $planet_color, 'HamburgSymbols.ttf', chr($pl_glyph[$sort_pos[$i]]));
```

Thank you!
ablase

Comment: http://php.net/imagecopyresampled  the rest is up to you.

Comment: Thank you Marc B, I'm a bit of a newbie but I'm at least grateful to be pointed in the right direction.